# AJAX - get response body in success and error

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

I am apologize for the stupid question, but I need your help. I need to get  information about response inside `AJAX`.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/register',
          data : registerRequestJSON,
          contentType:"application/json",
          success: function(data){
              $("#register_area").text();// need to show success
          },
          error: function(err) {
            $("#register_area").text("@text"); // @text = response error, it is will be errors: 324, 500, 404 or anythings else
          }
    });
```

How can I use response body? ([documentation Jquary.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is not working at the momment)

Comment: #register_area, is it a id of input type or any html tag?

Comment: `$("#register_area").text(data);` try this one.

Comment: the error function returns 3 values. first the jQHXR object, second the text status returned, third and finally the error that was invoked. you can use `error: function(a,b,c){ console.log(a,b,c) });` to get your information.

Comment: @OSSCube - you are right

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first param to error handler is `jqxhr`, it has the property `responseText` which will give the response body.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/register',
          data : registerRequestJSON,
          contentType:"application/json",
          success: function(data){
              $("#register_area").text();// need to show success
          },
          error: function(jqxhr) {
            $("#register_area").text(jqxhr.responseText); // @text = response error, it is will be errors: 324, 500, 404 or anythings else
          }
    });
```

Comment: I am calling 3rd party SMS API, I will get a response of unique id after success call.  but `data` is undefined, if response is  error `jqxhr.responseText` is undefined. Under browser Inspect page, i can see Source tab with API page name displaying the unique id / error message. How to get this response in code.?

Comment: @Vijayaraghavan can you share details about the response

Comment: I don't know how to brief the response, sample response is success- `614021564725478522`, or `x00 Invalid User Name`. I am able to manage this response using C# instead of JQuery. I Wish to manage it using Jquery.

Comment: how to manage the response in ajax for the response from API https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Sambatipuram&destinations=Aarapalayam&key=AIzaSyAzP_WMfyvUr90yJGn9lJqSeCxEASPUq1w&callback=jsonCallback&_=1517037897757

Comment: @Vijayaraghavan I don't think it is possible to use that api from the browser as CORS is not implemented there.
Instead you can have a server side enpoint in your server acting as a proxy and forward the requests to the google api