# With Backbone collection's "create", how do I check for errors in the backend?

Tags: http, rest, backbone.js

When I do this:

```
Comments.create(dat, {
                wait:true,
                success:function(){
                    main_alert('Posted successfully', 'success', 3000);
                },
                error:function(????){
                    main_alert('Error posting', 'error', 'default');
                }
            });
```

I want my server to return an "error" whenever I notice something wrong no the backend.  Currently, my server returns a JSON whenever the creation is complete.  How does my server return an error? And what would the error argument be?

Comment: see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15517359/1746258)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters that both `success` and `error` receive are `(model, response, options)`. [Here](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-fetch) is the reference. Under `response` there a property `responseText` with the text received from the server.

Comment: What should the server pass?

Comment: whatever you want, but I think passing a JSON object would be good. 
`{ error: "There was an error creating the comment }` for instance